# Docker React App: 404s will fallback to /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

I am building an React Javascript App with npm and want to deploy it on docker.
When I run the App locally with:

```
npm start
```

It all works just fine.
But then when I build a Docker Image and test it I get follwing error:

```
$ docker run react-app

> keycloak-react@0.1.0 start /
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY ./keycloak-react .
RUN npm install typescript
RUN npm install node-sass
RUN npm install sass
RUN npm install fibers
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I don't know what to do any ideas ?

Comment: What's the problem ? What's `npm start run` ? Shouldn't it be `npm run start` or simply `npm start` ?

Comment: with npm start I have the same issue

Comment: What is the issue ??

Comment: 404s will .... the same problem appears when using only npm start

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just fixed, let add stdin_open: true to docker-compose to fix it.

link info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Comment: Okay, Thank you. So what exactly should I do ?

Comment: What I mean by this, what should I change in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

I added `-i -t` flags in the `docker run` command and it worked fine for me

`-i` leaves the stdin of the container opened

`-t` assigns a `pseudo-tty` (for interactive session with shell)

My command was:

```
docker container run -i -t image_name
```

I think

```
docker run -i -t image_name
```

will work as well (don't know the real difference between the 2)

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options:

1. Add `stdin_open: true` to your docker-compose command
2. Add an `CI=true` as an environment variable
3. Downgrade your react-scripts to 3.4.0

I got stuck for several hours on this really annoying error but trying to use it on my CircleCI environment... But this is a Docker Question! (you might think), and yes it is, but CircleCI also does use Docker...
Anyway, I found myself in this same [Issue URL](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688) that @dwthiemn mentioned above and it turns out that [react-scripts 3.4.1](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.4.1) does looks for those specific values, otherwise the dev server is closed.

[image]

**But If by some mean you choose to downgrade your react-script version,** you should verify if there's any dependency conflict because of that